# How do I implement a try-refresh-retry cycle in Python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple Python wrapper around an API. I have a utility function in my wrapper class called `_call_api()` that is used by the other functions in the class. Here is the function:

```
    def _call_api(self, endpoint):
        '''
        utility function for calling API. handles pagination, rate limiting,
        token refreshes.
        :param endpoint: string of the endpoint being called.
                         everything after base url.
        :return: the decoded JSON from response
        '''
        endpoint += self.BASE_URL
        bearer = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token
        }

        response = request('GET', endpoint, headers=bearer)
        if response.status_code == 401: # access token is expired

            try:
                self.access_token = self._refresh_access_token()
            except InvalidGrant: # access revoked?
                pass

            bearer = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token
            }

            response = request('GET', endpoint, headers=bearer)

        return response.json()
```

While this code actually does work, I'd like a more Pythonic method of dealing with the access token refresh - as you can see, if the access token is expired, I request a new one, and if it's granted, I try to request the resource again. I'm curious if there's a method with less duplication.

Some notes:

- I only want to try to refresh the token once. If it fails, I can assume something went wrong - probably the user revoked my rights to access their resources.
- It seemed like maybe the `backoff` library could work but as far as I can tell there's no way to refresh the token before it retries.

Comment: As an *aside* you shouldn't invent dunder attributes like `__call_api__` and `__refresh_access_token__`...

Comment: `_name` - pseudo private; `__name` - name mangling; `__name__` - magic method. Your method is not magic at all.

Comment: So it should just be _call_api() and _refresh_access_token()? Assuming I'm trying to signal that those methods are for internal use only? Got it, makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up doing this:

```
    def _call(self, endpoint):
        '''
        just calls the API with the parameters given. used exclusively by _call_api()
        :param endpoint: string of the endpoint being called.
        :return: the decoded JSON from response
        '''
        endpoint += self.BASE_URL
        bearer = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token
        }

        response = request('GET', endpoint, headers=bearer)
        if response.status_code == 401:
            raise InvalidToken('Access Token is Expired.')
        return response.json()

    def _call_api(self, endpoint):
        '''
        utility function for calling API. this is the one that other functions
        of the class will use. handles pagination, rate limiting,
        token refreshes.
        :param endpoint: string of the endpoint being called.
                         passed on to _call()
        :return: the decoded JSON from response
        '''
        try:
            return self._call(endpoint)
        except InvalidToken:
            self.access_token = self._refresh_access_token()
            return self._call(endpoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
    def call(self, endpoint):
        endpoint += self.BASE_URL
        bearer = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token
        }
        response = request('GET', endpoint, headers=bearer)
        if response.status_code == 401: # access token is expired
            raise MyCustomAuthError(401)
        return response.json()

    def call_retry(self, endpoint):
        try:
            return self.call(endpoint)
        except (MyCustomAuthError,) as e: 
            try:
                self.access_token = self.refresh_access_token()
            except InvalidGrant: # access revoked?
                raise 
            return self.call(endpoint)
```

Another variation is around where the token is gotten.  The main reason I'd consider this approach is that a OOP design that requires you call `methodX` *before* calling `MethodY` tends to be a bit of a code smell, IMHO.

```
    def call(self, endpoint):
        endpoint += self.BASE_URL

        try:
            self.access_token = getattr(self, "access_token", None) or self.refresh_access_token()
        except InvalidGrant: # access revoked?
            raise 

        bearer = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token
        }
        response = request('GET', endpoint, headers=bearer)
        if response.status_code == 401: # access token is expired
            raise MyCustomAuthError(401)
        return response.json()

    def call_retry(self, endpoint):
        try:
            return self.call(endpoint)
        except (MyCustomAuthError,) as e: 
            self.access_token = ""
            return self.call(endpoint)
```

Comment: This is much better, thanks. I took this and changed it a little for my needs, and added another answer. Thank you!

Comment: @HoldenNelson txs.  you can always upvote or accept if it suited your needs.